# Using python df.replace with dict does not permanently change values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I generated a DataFrame that includes a column called "pred_categories" with numerical values of 0, 1, 2, and 3.  See below:

```
         fileids          pred_categories
0  /Saf/DA192069.txt                3
1  /Med/DA000038.txt                2
2  /Med/DA000040.txt                2
3  /Saf/DA191905.txt                3
4  /Med/DA180730.txt                2
```

I wrote a dict:

```
di = {3: "SAF", 2: "MED", 1: "FAC", 0: "ENV"}
```

And it works at first:

```
df.replace({'pred_categories': di})
Out[16]: 
          fileids           pred_categories
0   /Saf/DA192069.txt               SAF
1   /Med/DA000038.txt               MED
2   /Med/DA000040.txt               MED
3   /Saf/DA191905.txt               SAF
4   /Med/DA180730.txt               MED
5   /Saf/DA192307.txt               SAF
6   /Env/DA178021.txt               ENV
7   /Fac/DA358334.txt               FAC
8   /Env/DA178049.txt               ENV
9   /Env/DA178020.txt               ENV
10  /Env/DA178031.txt               ENV
11  /Med/DA000050.txt               MED
12  /Med/DA180720.txt               MED
13  /Med/DA000010.txt               MED
14  /Fac/DA358391.txt               FAC
```

but then when checking

```
 df.head()
```

it doesn't seem to permanently "save" it in the DataFrame.  Any pointers on what I'm doing wrong?

```
 print(df)
          fileids             pred_categories
  0   /Saf/DA192069.txt                3
  1   /Med/DA000038.txt                2
  2   /Med/DA000040.txt                2
  3   /Saf/DA191905.txt                3
  4   /Med/DA180730.txt                2
  5   /Saf/DA192307.txt                3
  6   /Env/DA178021.txt                0
  7   /Fac/DA358334.txt                1
  8   /Env/DA178049.txt                0
  9   /Env/DA178020.txt                0
  10  /Env/DA178031.txt                0
  11  /Med/DA000050.txt                2
  12  /Med/DA180720.txt                2
  13  /Med/DA000010.txt                2
  14  /Fac/DA358391.txt                1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per default `.replace()` returns changed DF, but it doesn't change it *in place*, so you have to do it this way:

```
df = df.replace({'pred_categories': di})
```

or

```
df.replace({'pred_categories': di}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I used the second option and it worked like a charm.

Comment: @nudro: Remember this trick for as long as you work with pandas because many of its features won't make any change inplace but do have an 'inplace' option. (and don't forget to accept MaxU's answer)

Comment: @ysearka thank you so much for the tips.  appreciate all the great help! accepted.